# Remove Polygons that don't Touch a Linear Feature

Tags: arcgis-pro

Is there a Geoprocessing tool that removes polygons that don't touch lines? I have a polygon layer and a line layer (Lakes and Rivers). I've tried Erase, Union, Intersect, and all of them either return just the linear features that intersect, but never just the polygons.  Am I missing some obvious tool?

Comment: Wouldn't a spatial selection and delete suffice (copying first to not lose the previous data could be important, so maybe select, flip the selection and save as a new feature class).

Comment: @Vince - Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot that the Spatial Join did exactly what I wanted - just needed more experience with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I found a way to do this right after I posted my question. It's just a spatial join with the intersect option.